# Git repository internal format explained

Tags: c#, git, github, libgit2, libgit2sharp

Is there any documentation on how Git stores files in his repository? I'm try to search over the Internet, but no usable results. Maybe I'm using incorrect query or maybe this is great secret — Git repository internal format?

Let me explain, why I need this rocket science information: I'm using C# to get file history form repository. But in `libgit2sharp` library it's not implemented currently. So (as a responsible person ;) I need to implement this feature by myself and contribute to community.

But after moving kernel sources to github I'm even don't know where start to my search.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: you could dig through other open source git implementations

Comment: Thanks Marian, could you please recommend one?

Comment: I recommend starting here http://progit.org/book/ch9-2.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The internal format of the repository is extremely simple. Git is in essence a user space file system that's content addressable.

Here's a thumbnail sketch.

### Objects

Git stores its internal data structures as [objects](http://book.git-scm.com/7_how_git_stores_objects.html). There are four kinds of objects: blobs (sort of like files), trees (sort of like directories), commits (snapshots of the file system at particular points in time along with information on how to reach there) and tags (pointers to commits useful for marking important ones).

If you look inside the `.git` directory of a repository, you'll find an `objects` directory that contains files named by the SHA-1 hash. Each of them represents an object. You can inspect them using plumbing `git cat-file` command. An example commit object from one of my repositories

```
noufal@sanitarium% git cat-file -p 7347addd901afc7d237a3e9c9512c9b0d05c6cf7
tree c45d8922787a3f801c0253b1644ef6933d79fd4a
parent 4ee56fbe52912d3b21b3577b4a82849045e9ff3f
author Noufal Ibrahim <noufal@..> 1322165467 +0530
committer Noufal Ibrahim <noufal@..> 1322165467 +0530

Added a .md extension to README
```

You can also see the the object itself at `.git/objects/73/47addd901afc7d237a3e9c9512c9b0d05c6cf7`.

You can examine other objects like this. Each commit points to a tree representing the file system at that point in time and has one (or more in case of merge commits) parent.

Objects are stored as single files in the `objects` directory. These are called loose objects. When you run `git gc`, objects that can no longer be reached are pruned and the remaining are packed together into a a single file and delta compressed. This is more space efficient and compacts the repository. After you run gc, you can look at the `.git/objects/pack/` directory to see git packfiles. To unpack them, you can use the plumbing command `git unpack-objects` command. The `.git/objects/info/packs` file contains a list of packfiles that are currently present.

### References

The next thing you need to know is what references are. These are pointers to certain commits or objects. Your branches and other such things are implemented as references. There are two kinds "real" (which are like hard links in a file system) and "symbolic" (which are pointers to real references - like symbolic links).

These are located in the `.git/refs` directory. For example, in the above repository, I'm on the `master` branch. My latest commit is

```
noufal@sanitarium% git log -1
commit 7347addd901afc7d237a3e9c9512c9b0d05c6cf7
Author: Noufal Ibrahim <noufal@...>
Date:   Fri Nov 25 01:41:07 2011 +0530

    Added a .md extension to README
```

You can see that my `master` reference located at `.git/refs/heads/master` points to this commit.

```
noufal@sanitarium% more .git/refs/heads/master
7347addd901afc7d237a3e9c9512c9b0d05c6cf7
```

The current branch is stored in the symbolic reference `HEAD` located at `.git/HEAD`. Here it is

```
noufal@sanitarium% more .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

It will change if you switch branches.

Similarly, tags are references like this too (but they are not movable unlike branches).

The entire repository is managed using just a DAG of commits (each of which points to a tree  representing the files at a point in time) and references that point to various commits on the DAG so that you can manipulate them.

### Further reading

- I have a presentation which I use for my git trainings up [here](http://nibrahim.net.in/presentations/git/index.html) that explains some of this.
- The community book at http://book.git-scm.com/ has some sections on the internals.
- Scott Chacon's Pro Git book has a section on [internals](http://progit.org/book/ch9-0.html)
- He also has a [peepcode PDF](http://peepcode.com/products/git-internals-pdf) just about the internals.

Comment: Can you address what happens when `git gc` is run? It's my understanding that objects are packed into a single file.

Comment: Very informative. I suppose it's going to be hard for Alexey to manually parse a generic database without invoking any git commands.

Comment: Thanks. One way of parsing the database is to use the git *plumbing* commands via. some subprocess interface and parse the replies. The plumbing is the API and so the library will be more robust (although slower). I believe the ruby gem grit works this way. The other option would be to actually implement C# functions to parse the database which is more work and harder to maintain but will be faster and more "native".

Comment: This is the main idea, I finally got some time to contribute **libgit2** and make it a bit more usable for real projects. It looks like a really bad joke — git library not able to show file revisions history.

Comment: Check out [grit](http://grit.rubyforge.org/). It is a Ruby API for git maintained by the github guys. I quite like the API.

Comment: Thanks!
Hm... They say: *To this end, some of the interactions with Git repositories are done by shelling out to the system‘s `git` command*... 

Hope they implemented `git log` command not in similar manner...

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim, are you sure `grit` supports something `git log --follow` syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure. You can get a list of commits starting from a treeish though and then possibly implement the cross rename bit in your application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5343/discussion-between-alexey-shytikov-and-noufal-ibrahim)

Comment: There's also a fifth type of object: Note objects. See: http://schacon.github.com/git/git-notes.html

Comment: @rFactor. Interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @Tower: Notes aren't an object type; they're stored exactly the same way as a regular history.